# Editar registro modal com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um modal para editar usuário e quando tem ng-model no input não exibe o value para editar. O que posso estar fazendo de errado.

```js
$scope.updateUser = function(userId){
    var id = userId;
    $http.get("models/retornaUser.php?id=" + id).then(function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
        $scope.userLogin = $scope.user[0].userLogin;
        $scope.userName = $scope.user[0].userName;
        $scope.userFone = $scope.user[0].userFone;
        $scope.userEmail = $scope.user[0].userEmail;
        $scope.userNivel = $scope.user[0].userNivel;
    });
}
```

```html
// button qe chama a modal passando id
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-indigo px-2" ng-click="updateUser(user.userId)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUser"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></button>

// input modal com validacao de telefone
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="userUFone">Fone</label>
  <input type="text" name="userUFone" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="userUFone" ng-model="formDataUp.userUFone" ui-br-phone-number-mask maxlength="15" value="{{userFone}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Ricardo! Se possível validar minha resposta! :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá tudo bem? Então o valor que você deseja iniciar no input deve ser preenchido pelo ng-model, nele vai ocorrer o data-bind! Pelo que entendi você carrega o valor inicial de um endpoint e deseja edita-lo e atribuir ao ***formDataUp.userUFone***. Então acredito que você possa fazer da seguinte forma:

```
 $scope.updateUser = function(userId){
    var id = userId;
    $http.get("models/retornaUser.php?id=" + id).then(function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
        $scope.userLogin = $scope.user[0].userLogin;
        $scope.userName = $scope.user[0].userName;
        $scope.userFone = $scope.user[0].userFone;
        $scope.userEmail = $scope.user[0].userEmail;
        $scope.userNivel = $scope.user[0].userNivel;
        $scope.formDataUp.userUFone = $scope.userFone;
    });
}

// button qe chama a modal passando id
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-indigo px-2" ng-click="updateUser(user.userId)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUser"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></button>

// input modal com validacao de telefone
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="userUFone">Fone</label>
  <input type="text" name="userUFone" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="userUFone" ng-model="formDataUp.userUFone" ui-br-phone-number-mask maxlength="15">
</div>
```

Removi o value do input e atualizei o model formDataUp.userUFone quando o valor é carregado do endpoint.

Qualquer dúvida sobre como funciona o carregamento do input no angular pode ver [aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!

Comment: Ricardo! Se possível validar minha resposta! :)